# Incorrect Keymapping on Pi400

Tags: keyboard, pi, keymapping, debian-based

I have loaded the latest version of Raspberry Pi OS (32-bit) to a pi400, but the keymapping is odd. For instance, my backslash '\' Key types the pound sign '#'. Other keys are also mapped oddly too.

I first checked the keyboard-mapping via

```
sudo raspi-config
```

and then from the prompt selected Localization Options > Keyboard > Configuring keyboard-configuration

For Keyboard Model, I selected 'Generic 101-key PC' as per [this pihut article](https://support.thepihut.com/hc/en-us/articles/360016773098-Pi400-Incorrect-Keyboard-Layout) suggestion.

I saved and rebooted; no luck.

I found [a tutorial](https://ictsolved.github.io/remap-key-in-linux/) on remapping keys, but requires some bash scripting to run on start, which seems messy.

Maybe choosing a different Keyboard model in keyboard-configuration would solve the issue instead?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out my locale was set to UK.

I used the following command to change my keyboard region and it fixed the issue

```
setxkbmap us
```